# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo de un correo, con imap?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy descargando archivos de correos no leídos, ya logramos descargar los archivos adjuntos y los embebidos, pero no hemos podido descargar los adjuntos cuando viene combinado con embebido. El código que estamos utilizando es el siguiente

```
private void buscarMensajes()
    {
        this.CorreosElectronicos = new List<MicrosistemasEmail>();
        string strNombreArchivo = "";

        client.Behavior.ExamineFolders = true;
        client.Behavior.FolderTreeBrowseMode = FolderTreeBrowseMode.Full;
        client.Behavior.AutoDownloadBodyOnAccess = true;
        client.Behavior.AutoGenerateMissingBody = true;
        client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = MessageFetchMode.Full;
        client.Behavior.AutoPopulateFolderMessages = true;

        var listadirectorios = client.Folders.Where(x => x.Name == "INBOX").AsEnumerable();

        foreach (Folder folder in listadirectorios)
        {
            //Filtro Fechas 
            this.FechaFinal = this.FechaFinal.AddDays(1);

            string strDiaInicial = this.FechaInicial.Day.ToString("00");
            string strMesInicial = this.FechaInicial.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
            string strAnioInicial = this.FechaInicial.Year.ToString();

            string strDiaFinal = this.FechaFinal.Day.ToString("00");
            string strMesFinal = this.FechaFinal.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
            string strAnioFinal = this.FechaFinal.Year.ToString();


            //Filtro No leidos - Todos
            string strFiltro = String.Format("SINCE {0}-{1}-{2} BEFORE {3}-{4}-{5} {6} ",
                                       strDiaInicial,
                                       strMesInicial,
                                       strAnioInicial,
                                       strDiaFinal,
                                       strMesFinal,
                                       strAnioFinal,
                                       (this.MensajesNoLeidos == true ? "UNSEEN" : "ALL"));
            
            IEnumerable<Message> mensajesFiltrados = folder.Search(strFiltro/*MessageFetchMode.Full,10*/);

            //Filtro y que contenga Adjuntos. Independientes o Embebidos
            mensajesFiltrados = mensajesFiltrados.Where(x => x.Attachments.Count() > 0 || x.EmbeddedResources.Count() > 0);

            foreach (Message message in mensajesFiltrados)
            {
                strNombreArchivo = "";
                IEnumerable<Attachment> ArchivosAdjuntosFiltrados = null;

                //Se revisa si el Archivo Adjunto viene de manera independiente
                if (message.Attachments.Count() > 0)
                {
                    ArchivosAdjuntosFiltrados = message.Attachments.Where(x => x.ContentType.MediaType == "text/xml" && x.ContentType.MediaType == "text/pdf");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Se revisa si el Archivo Adjunto viene como Recurso Embebido
                    if (message.EmbeddedResources.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        ArchivosAdjuntosFiltrados = message.EmbeddedResources.Where(x => x.ContentType.MediaType == "text/xml" && x.ContentType.MediaType == "text/pdf");
                    }
                }

                foreach (Attachment atachemtn in ArchivosAdjuntosFiltrados)
                {
                    strNombreArchivo = atachemtn.FileName;

                    if (strNombreArchivo != String.Empty) {

                        atachemtn.Download();
                        atachemtn.Save(strRutaDescargas, atachemtn.FileName);

                        this.CorreosElectronicos.Add(new MicrosistemasEmail()
                        {
                            adjunto = (strNombreArchivo != String.Empty ? true : false),
                            asunto = message.Subject,
                            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(message.Date),
                            id = message.UId.ToString(),
                            nombreArchivo = strNombreArchivo,
                            rutaArchivo = this.strRutaDescargas,
                            validado = false
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Colocamos por separado un proceso para adjuntos y otro para embebidos.

Si el correo solo tiene adjuntos, solo tiene archivos embebidos, no hay problema, con este código se descargan, pero si los archivos vienen adjuntos y hay una imagen de firma que está embebido, solo descargo la imagen de la firma y no los adjuntos.